# Mean Comparison test for 3 related samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I have ratio scale data for 3 related samples. What is the statistical test that I can use to check whether there's any significant difference between the 3 groups? (I tried Friedman, but I'm doubtful whether it can be used for ratio scale data.)

https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/friedman-test-using-spss-statistics.php

This cite says Friedman test can be used for continuous scale data as well, but I need to make sure about it as this is the only place I found that fact. In every other place, it speaks about ratio scale data.

NOTE:
I collected data from 15 people. i.e. sample size is 15. The same 15 people faced the 3 different situations where we need to compare

Comment: related = dependent samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment you clarifies

> collected data from 15 people. i.e. sample size is 15. The same 15
>   people faced the 3 different situations where we need to compare

that is information that really needs to be in the post itself! please edit.  So one simple model for your situation is
$$
   y_{ij}=\mu+\tau_i+\beta_j+\epsilon_{ij}
$$ with $i=1,2,\dotsc,15$ indexing the persons and $\beta_j, j=1,2,3$ indexing the groups. As written this is a *mixed model* and could be analyzed as such, or traditionally as *repeated measurement ANOVA*. If you use R, you could start with something like

```
lme4::lmer(y ~ groups + (1 | person), data=your_data_frame)
```

with data in long format. Also search this site for repeated measures, and read up on mixed models!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did the edit as you requested. Mixed models are new to me. Will check further on it

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is a ratio scale data why don't you try to use ANOVA for testing. It is a parametric test as compared to the non-parametric Friedman.

Comment: If OP has data collected according to a block design, Friedman might be OK. But you would have to specify carefully _what kind_ of ANOVA to use.

Comment: Cannot use ANOVA, since the samples are not independent. They are related (dependent samples)

Comment: If you really want to use the Friedman test, then look at the example at the end of the [R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/friedman.test.html) for that test. You have a design just like the baseball example, except you have 15 subj as 'blocks' (not 22 players) and you have three methods to compare. The hypothesis test will compare your 3 groups. // However, if your data have nearly normal residuals, you can use the ANOVA model suggested by @Kjetilbhalversen (+1). Maybe make a normal probability plot of residuals at the end to verify their near normality.

Comment: Is normality the only requirement for ANOVA? Don't the data should be independent?

Comment: https://sites.ualberta.ca/~lkgray/uploads/7/3/6/2/7362679/slides_-_anova_assumptions.pdf